# Html Css span within div not displays text

Tags: html, css

My span does not display text on hover and I do not know why. Here is my code:

HTML

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

div.box {
  margin: 0 auto;
  border:1px solid red;
  font-size: 0;
  width: 50%;
  --R:150px; /* radius */
  --m:5px;   /* margin */
  --t:50px;  /* distance from top */
}

p {
  font-size: 20px;
}

div.box p {
  width: 50%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0 var(--m);
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  text-align: justify;
}

div.box p:before {
  content: "";
  width: var(--R);
  height: calc(2*var(--R));
  padding:var(--m) 0 var(--m) var(--m);
  margin-top:var(--t);
  background:var(--img);
  background-size:200% 100%;
  shape-outside: circle(var(--R) at var(--d,right) calc(-1*var(--m)) top calc(50% + var(--t)/2));
  float: right;
  border-radius: 500px 0 0 500px;
  margin-right:calc(-1*var(--m));
}

div.box p:last-child:before {
  float: left;
  padding:var(--m) var(--m) var(--m) 0;
  --d:left;
  background-position:right;
  border-radius:0 500px 500px 0;
  margin-left:calc(-1*var(--m));
  margin-right:0;
}

i*,*::before,*::after {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.box .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px 0;
  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
}

.box:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" style="--img:url(https://jakuwegiel.web.app/assets/images/DSC_0925a-1.png)">
 <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
 <p>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
  <p>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
</div>
```

If you need to see result just take a look at [my codepen](https://codepen.io/Kiubaz/pen/VwKdGOe?editors=1100). Tell me if you need something more. I need some more text. I do not know what else I need to add, I wrote everything you need. I did exactly like on [this](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_tooltip) website but the text is not visible, but background of span is.

Comment: Why do you .box:hover shouldn't it be tooltip:hover?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following line of code: `font-size: 20px;`

Over here:

```html
.box .tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 50px 0;

    /* Position the tooltip */
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: but what about this example? https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_tooltip_left . When I use p everything is messed up.

Comment: Sorry, please try the updated answer... you need to use the CSS for font-size (which you'd given to the p tag) The value doesn't matter, any non-zero value would do

Comment: @jestemrandomem, it works on the codepen so I assume that there's no problem...?